# How do I sync the Visual Studio Code (vscode) theme to use my OS light/dark color scheme?

Tags: macos, system-settings, visual-studio-code

MacOS now supports both "Light" and "Dark" mode (found in "System Preferences", "General", "Appearance").

How can I make VS Code automatically change its theme to be light or dark, when I change my MacOS "Appearance"?

Comment: This is a vscode question, not an Apple question.

Comment: @ThaJay This question is using software on Apple hardware, so it's perfectly on-topic.

Comment: This is the same across all OS that have light and dark mode so it's purely about vscode. I used this answer on my Windows install.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

1. Enable Auto Detect (Search in Settings: `window.autoDetectColorScheme`)
2. Customize Color Themes (Search in Settings: `workbench preferred color theme`)

---

### More Detail ([Visual Studio Code Themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_auto-switch-based-on-os-color-scheme)):

> Auto switch based on OS color scheme Windows and macOS support light and dark color schemes. There is a setting, `window.autoDetectColorScheme`, that instructs VS Code to listen to changes to the OS's color scheme and switch to a matching theme accordingly.
>
> To customize the themes that are used when a color scheme changes, you can set the preferred light, dark, and high contrast themes with the settings:
>
> `workbench.preferredLightColorTheme` - defaults to "Default Light+"
> `workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme` - defaults to "Default Dark+"
> `workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme` - defaults to "Default High Contrast"
> `workbench.preferredHighContrastLightColorTheme` - defaults to "Default High Contrast Light"

Comment: And is it possible to manually override this setting? Like having a switch/command that switches to the preferred dark theme, even though my system setting is light.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I just manually make the switch (instructions below - quite easy!). Haven’t looked for a way to switch based on the workbench setting. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score 57):

Go to settings and search for `theme` -> `Auto Detect Color Scheme`

[image]

Comment: Removed. Will you edit yours, @vdegenne?

Answer (score 0):

I also found that property "workbench.colorTheme" is not well working with auto theme switcher. So I added it to ignore and now all works like a charm.

```
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Light",
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
    "workbench.colorTheme"
  ],
```